# How to iterate over array of associated arrays in zsh

Tags: arrays, zsh

Here is an example that runs how I want it to in bash

```bash
declare -A price_oracle=(
  [name]="price_oracle_name"
  [active]=true
)

declare -A market=(
  [name]="market_name"
  [active]=true
)

declare -a contract_list=(
  price_oracle
  market
)

for contract in "${contract_list[@]}"; do
  declare -n lst="$contract"
  if ${lst[is_active]}; then
    echo "Importing schema for $contract contract"
    wasm-cli import -s --name $contract contracts/$contract/schema
  fi
done
```

How can this same functionality be accomplished in zsh? `declare -n` is not valid in zsh.

Comment: Beside the point, but `is_active` should be `active`. That line only seems to work because a null command has a 0 exit status, so you might want to find a way to mitigate that, like `[[ ${lst[active]} == true ]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nested parameter expansion flag `(P)` can be used instead of a bash `nameref`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

declare -A price_oracle=(
  [name]=price_oracle_name
  [active]=true
)

declare -A market=(
  [name]=market_name
  [active]=true
)

declare -a contract_list=(
  price_oracle
  market
)

for contract in $contract_list; do
  local -A lst=("${(Pkv@)contract}")
  if ${lst[active]}; then
    echo "Importing schema for $contract contract"
    wasm-cli import -s --name ${lst[name]} contracts/$contract/schema
  fi
done
```

To work with the associative array, this also uses the key `(k)`, value `(v)`, and array separation `(@)` expansion flags. These are described in the `zshexpn` man page and the online [zsh documentation](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags).

Comment: Thank you SO much! I was beginning to lose hope. This was exactly what I needed. I really appreciate you taking the time to help out.